# Merriweather Sans font issue in IE9 and older

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

This particular font doesn't seem to be working properly in IE9 and older.

It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and IE10, but in IE9, **uppercase letters with acute accent** simply doesn't appear.

This issue happens not only when I try to import the font to my website, but also on google.com/fonts, when I'm trying to preview it.

Has anyone faced any similar issue with this font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that some Google fonts don't seem to be really cross-browser and may cause some issues like this one with Merriweather + IE9. I solved it by generating the font using [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and importing it with @font-face.